# Unable to add ForegroundColorSpan

Tags: android, spannable

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello World");
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.text_blue);
sb.setSpan(fcs, 5, 11,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image]

**res/Values/color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_blue">#FF39ACEE</color>
</resources>
```

The color has changed but to something else, rather than the blue color I wanted.

Thank You.

Comment: it gives me the right color tried it on my emulator

Comment: Gives me me right color as well, both on emulator and on device, which emulator/device are you checking?? Check on real device if possible..

Comment: I am trying it on a device.

Comment: strange i changed the length and it does not display blue color for the text. changed to  `sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)` and this worked `new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);` tested on emulator

Comment: @Raghunandan which one worked?

Comment: @user1537779 check my post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello World");
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.text_blue);
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs  =new ForegroundColorSpan(color);
    sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, sb.length(),0);
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(sb);
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_blue">#FF39ACEE</color>
</resources>
```

Snap

[image]

The below did not work

```
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.text_blue);
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, sb.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: **Worked:** This `int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.text_blue);
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs  =new ForegroundColorSpan(color);` did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

In the case of the question - the colour passed into the `ForegroundColorSpan` was not yet resolved.

However on a side note, adding a `ForegroundColorSpan` to a `TextView` that has the attribute `allCaps="true"` will not work.

Remove the `allCaps` attribute, programatically change the capitalisation of the string BEFORE passing it to the constructor the `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

Some time you will use more than one span, they may influence each other. you should set ForegroundColorSpan at last.

Comment: very important note when implementing multiple spans!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `R.color.XXX` you are not passing the *color int*, rather you are passing the `id` of this resource in the generated `R` class - which is also an int, but one *randomly* generated by android. It's not your color, but it parses as one, and that's why your text gets a weird color.

To extract the *literal color int* from the *id int* you need to use something like `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.XXX)`

This is confusing since in some cases we can set resources directly with `R` id's, such as with `TextView.setText(int resId)`.

How can we tell? -simply check the annotation on the argument in the given function.

`@ColorInt` is expecting a literal color (like `0x0000ff` -blue), such as in `ForegroundColorSpan(@ColorInt int color)`.

`@ColorRes` is expecting an id int(`R.color.blue`), such as `ContextCompat.getColor(@NonNull Context context, @ColorRes int id)`