# Android - Set More Than One Color For Alert Dialog Text

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a [AlertDialog](https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#alert-dialog) that has multiple lines of text. I am looking to have a different color for each line of text. Any ideas on how one would go about this? Is it possible to set a span foreground color to a string variable?

API 30

[image]

```
    // Create Material Dialog
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_dialog_title));
    SpannableString string = new SpannableString(
            "Text: " + variable1 +
            "\n\nText: " + variable2);
    string.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, string.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(string);
    dialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: Use a ForegroundColorSpan

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan), you can use [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan) to color a segment of the text which goes into the `MaterialAlertDialog`,

```kotlin
val materialAlertDialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder( this )
val message = SpannableString( "Hello World" ).apply {
    setSpan( ForegroundColorSpan( Color.BLUE ) , 6 , 11 , SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE )
}
val dialog = materialAlertDialogBuilder.run {
    setTitle( "Some Title" )
    setMessage( message )
    create()
}
dialog.show()
```

You may also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720436/unable-to-add-foregroundcolorspan) discussion.

The output ( on API level 28 ):
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible to set the color to a string variable, and then add that variable plus other variables to the setMessage parameter? 
<br/>
<br/>var1 = var1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, var1.length(), <br/>SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
<br/>string = var1 + var2;
<br/>.setMessage(string);